# Microsoft Azure emotion api returns [ "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found"] error

Tags: python, azure, computer-vision

I am trying to test some images with Microsoft Azure emotion API. Following the instruction on [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/emotion/quickstarts/python), I get { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" } error all the time. And my codes are modified from the website as following:

```
########### Python 2.7 #############
import httplib, urllib, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers. Replace the placeholder key below with your subscription key.
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'key',
}

params = urllib.urlencode({ })

# Replace the example URL below with the URL of the image you want to analyze.
body = "{ 'url':'http://www.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/35391452-5457-431A-A75B859471FAB0B3.jpg' }"

try:
    # NOTE: You must use the same region in your REST call as you used to obtain your subscription keys.
    #   For example, if you obtained your subscription keys from westcentralus, replace "westus" in the 
    #   URL below with "westcentralus".
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognize?%s" % params, body, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
  print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Also, when I enter the endpoint url in my browser, which is https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/emotion/v1.0 , it shows { "error": { "code": "ResourceNotFound", "message": "resource not found." } }. I am not sure whether this is related to the error.

Did anybody meet this problem or can anyone give me some advice on solving the problem? Thanks!

Comment: did you solve this issue =?

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced the same issue, whatever the status code & error message you got

> [message:protected] => Fail:
> Code: 404
> Value: Not Found
> details (if any): Resource not found for the segment 'Jobs'..

Check your params, if you are passing to the azure with already processed JobId & all the stuff. Then you will get the issue. You need to cross-check whether your passing file information is already processed or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I tried to reproduce your issue successfully, which was caused by the `westcentralus` host does not exist, as below.

[image]

Please change the host `westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com` to `westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com` in your code, then it works.